# Referenced table is not coming in my model through entity framework 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

I am using MVC 4 and entity framework 5.0, i have a database and this database contains 6 tables named as following.

```
tblUser_family
tblUser_location
tblUser_info
tblUser_photo
tblUser_settings
tblUser_social
```

when i am creating the .edmx file then only 5 tables are coming in designer one table "tblUser_settings" is not coming, while all tables are connected through foreginKeys.

I am getting following error

***Error    1   Error 6004: The table 'Community.dbo.tblUser_settings' is referenced by a relationship, but cannot be found.***

Comment: There must be a constraint active on that table and its not found while creating the model and hence, the error. You might want to check that in your SQL by checking the CREATE script of that table.

Comment: tblUser_setting using tblUser_info => user_id (primary_key ) as foreignKey.

so do you mean to remove this constraint ?

Comment: Is tblUser_setting referenced by some other table in your database in any way ?

Comment: No, it is not referenced by any other table.

Comment: Try for once, removing the tblUser_info foreign key constraint from that table and check if it works.

Comment: ok, i check again and let you know.

Comment: i tried but its not working.

Comment: this time i havn't get error but not found tblUser_setting table also as usual.

Comment: Try this, CTRL+A all the entities in your model, delete them and update model from database again entirely.

Comment: Tried but not worked.

Comment: Double check if the table is present in the context.cs file and if it only not showing in your designer view.

Comment: No, this table also not present in context.cs, i don't think sql server version will make any differece, right now i am using VS2014 express (due to company requirement)

Comment: Right click on your designer view and then on Update model from database. After that a window will open and there click on refresh and then on tables and then finish. Check if that works.

Comment: before pressing finish i can see In Refresh tab that table is not visible, and after pressing finish, i can't see that table in designer.

Comment: If its possible, just delete that table from SQL server, recreate it and then try to update your model entirely again.

Comment: yes that i can try and let you know.

Comment: I deleted and recreated table then made foreginkey and then attached from entityFramework and this time also not worked.

Comment: Did it show that error it was showing previously /

Comment: Ohh yes, i have not paid attention on that, this time no error but table is missing.

Comment: Lol. This is getting interesting. Never experienced such stuff. See this link and follow steps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572125/entity-framework-not-generating-classes-for-tables-or-procedures

Comment: See this also : http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/453

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Recently i have resolved my issue, problem was i had a main table which has a primary key, and that primary key was mapped with my missing table's column in that column i set **"Allow null"**, as i changed "Allow not null", and update my data model from Entity framework 5.0, it was visible in my solution.

Thank you for all suggestions.

Comment: I didn't  created the **primary key** for my table

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem, in my case I didn't have created the primary key to my table, so I just set it and I could update my EDMX.

Answer (score 5):

make sure you have "not null" in the declaration of FK

Answer (score 2):

My issue was when creating the foreign keys I didn't specify NOT NULL.  I made the change and the table imported just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The tables that don't have primary key won't be read by Edmx

Comment: Why does that even happen?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it was that I forgot to "Write Changes". I used to work with MSSQL Server but with DB Browser for SQLite even after we run the script we still need to  "Write Changes"  / Ctrl + S   to reflect them in the the database. Also make sure FKs are not null and in the same data type.  not int but Integer etc. Also for EDMX you need to define PK in your tables. Weak entities won't be included in EDMX.

Comment: What´s a "weak entity"?

Comment: Entities / Tables which don't have a primary key defined are considered weak entities.

Answer (score 0):

For foreign keys, I didn't specify NOT NULL in reference tables. I updated table and update edmx file to resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same issue of not getting data from the reference table connected through a foreign key with the primary table. When I was trying to get the table data from DbContext class. Previously I was fetching the data using:

```
orders = _context.Orders.ToList();
```

I am not getting the reference table data. Hence, I used the "Include" functionality.

```
orders = _context.Orders.Include(p => p.Person).ToList();
```

This solution worked for me.

Comment: `Include` is not related to the issue in the question. The issue is something entirely different.